# Flutter Build Issue

Tags: android, flutter

When I try to open the application made with Flutter on the test device, I get the following error. I tried many methods but could not get a successful result. What do you think is the error and how can I resolve it?

```html
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:179:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as _Provider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:180:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 2m 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the version 2.0.1 of the Provider Library.

This version isn't compatible with the newest versions of Flutter, since the `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` was deprecated in Flutter 1.12

You have two choices here, either downgrade the version of Flutter you're using to be below 1.12, or upgrade your [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/versions) import to a newer one (I strongly recommend you to pick the second option !)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

Yesterday I Just restarted my pc and got this issue. I tried to search for the solution to this problem but nothing works in my case.

**Solution**

Just delete your flutter folder (Flutter Source) and then reinstall it. Your problem will solve.